# Using Compass watch In Non-Rails project Hangs

Tags: configuration, config, compass-sass, watch, compass-rails

I'm using compass with a non-Rails project. I have a config file at:

`config/compass.rb`

My config file looks like this:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "./example"
sass_dir = "./example/sass"
images_dir = "./example/images"
javascripts_dir = "./example/js"

output_style = :compressed
relative_assets = true
```

And I'm starting Compass using:

`compass watch -c config/compass.rb`

When I run this, compass just hangs. If I run compass using `--trace` and quit, I get the following stack-trace:

```
^CInterrupt on line ["18"] of /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-rails-2.0.0/lib/compass-rails.rb:
  /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-rails-2.0.0/lib/compass-rails.rb:116:in `configuration'
  /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:21:in `configuration_for'
  /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/compass/configuration.rb:139:in `add_configuration'
  /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:79:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:37:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
  /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
  /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:41:in `initialize'
```

So it appears that rather than using the `compass` gem, calling `compass watch` is using `compass-rails` which expects configuration arguments I'm not supplying and hangs.

`$ which compass` returns: `/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/compass`

**Why is this and how can I work around it?**

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I used Bundler and ran:

`$ be compass watch -c ./config/compass.rb`

Note `be` is an alias for `bundle exec`.

I'm still unsure how `compass-rails` was hooking into `compass`.